# How to make transition when expression change

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

**Are there any way to make transition when expression was change**  with angular for ionic

This my html code. I want to make transition of the `<div class="fadeIn">{{ phrase }}</div>` when expression change ( {{ phrase }} )

```
<div class="fadeIn">{{ phrase }}</div> /*I use animate.css framework*/
<button ion-button (click)="previous()">Previous</button>
<button ion-button (click)="next()">Next</button>
```

TypeScript file

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

export class RecipePage implements OnInit{

  phrase: string;
  ngOnInit() { this.phrase = "Hi"; }
  next() { this.phrase = "Next phrase"; }
  previous() { this.phrase = "Previous phrase"; }

}
```

when I click button the text was change but the animation not working because I use typescript to change the text `this.phrase = "here";`

Are there way to make transition when expression was change by typescript

Answer (score 0):

You can use Animate css, which is working fine with any kind of component (Text, image etc)

[animate.css](https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/)

Comment: Hi **Rohan J Mohite** thanks for your answer I am sorry I don't explain my question good. but I don't need for framework (animate.css), what I need is How to transition text when expression was change for example if value of expression  `{{ phrase }}` is **Hello**, now if I change this to **Hi** `this.phrase = "Hi";` I want to appear the text with animation. but now when I use animation for example (animate.css) the animation is not working because the value was change by typescript `this.phrase = "Here";` are there any way to make animation working when value change by typescript